# Byte conversion to INT64, under the hood

Tags: c#, byte, data-conversion

Good day. For a current project I need to know how datatypes are represented as bytes. For example, if I use :

```
long three = 500;var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(three);
```

I get the values 244,1,0,0,0,0,0,0. I get that it is a 64 bit value, and 8 bits go int a bit, thus are there 8 bytes. But how does 244 and 1 makeup 500? I tried Googling it, but all I get is use BitConverter. I need to know how the bitconverter works under the hood. If anybody can perhaps point me to an article or explain how this stuff works, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of 244 + 256? What do you think that 1 might mean?

Comment: `244 + 256 * 1 + 256 * 256 * 0 + ... + 256 * ... * 256 * 0 == 500`

Comment: If you aren't used to that kind of maths, think of it this way. What does 123, in normal maths, mean? It means 1 x 10^2 + 2 x 10^1 + 3 * 10^0. Your example is the exact same except for two things. a) The digits are in reverse order. It is not **10** to the power of something, it is **256** to the power of something (since a byte is 8 bits - which can store up to 256).

Comment: Awesome, it makes sense to me now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple.

```
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)1); // {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)10); // {10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)100); // {100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)255); // {255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)256); // {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}; this 1 is 256
BitConverter.GetBytes((long)500); // {244,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}; this is yours 500 = 244 + 1 * 256
```

If you need source code you should check Microsoft GitHub since implementation is open source :)
https://github.com/dotnet

Comment: I did not know the .Net source is open. I thought it was only .NetCore that is opensource. This is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs):

```
// Converts a long into an array of bytes with length 
// eight.
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(long value)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<byte[]>().Length == 8);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    fixed(byte* b = bytes)
        *((long*)b) = value;
    return bytes;
}
```